# How to loop through a json file and change specific values based on specific criterias

Tags: python, text-processing

I am trying to make a python script in which I can change a specific value based on a specific location inside a file for this example a json file specifically.

The json file is about 100k long there are multiple areas specified with `"name": "Box #14", "name": "Box #16", "name": "Box #17"` and the list keeps going. For each name it comes an image field just below the name e.g. `"image": ".png"`, I want to edit that `.png` value to be based on a specific value depending on the name number. For example if `"name": "Box #14` then `"image": "13.png"` and if `"name": "Box #15 then` `"image": "14.png"` and so on...

What I got so far is:

```
import re
import sys

i = 0
++i

PAT = re.compile('"image": ".png"')

KEYWORDS_PATH = 'images.json'
KEYWORDS = open(KEYWORDS_PATH).read().splitlines()

names = ['"name": ".*"']


def check_all(check, ws):
    return all(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(w), check) for w in ws)


with open('images.json') as inp, open('output.json', 'w') as out:

    for name in names:
        if names in KEYWORDS:
            print('Removed the keyword - %s' % names)
            sys.exit()
    for line in inp:
        out.write(PAT.sub('"image": "%s.png"' % i, line))
```

this is making everything 0.png

Update:

this is one examples inside the json file

```
[
 {
   "name": "Box #14",
   "image": ".png",
   "attributes": [
     {
       "trait_type": "Size",
       "value": "0.8 inch"
     }   
   ]
     "files": [
       {
         "url": ".png",
         "type": "image/png"
       }
     ]
   }
 },

{
   "name": "Box #15",
   "image": ".png",
   "attributes": [
     {
       "trait_type": "Size",
       "value": "2.8 inch"
     }   
   ]
     "files": [
       {
         "url": ".png",
         "type": "image/png"
       }
     ]
   }
 }
]
```

All I want to do is replace the .png inside the image field with whatever the number on the name is but a digit below e.g. as shown above Box #14 name I want the image to be replaced from .png to 13.png

Comment: Hi, I think you can take each line and do `line.split("#")[1]` to get the line number.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I understand your code - 
1. why are you looping over `int` and not over `KEYWORDS` which is already split to lines?     
2. why are you checking `if names in KEYWORDS`?

Comment: When you say *"it comes an image field just below the name"*, do you mean in the same level of the hierarchy? Because JSON is unordered, so if there are additional keys you can't rely on the fact that it will really be the line below or something.

Comment: Also - you're replacing everything with `i` which is set to `0` in the beginning of your code and doesn't change in every loop.

Comment: @pugi I was testing different ways to do it, I wasn't getting a result with the `if names in KEYWORDS` so I was trying to see if I could increment by doing `++I` note I am not very good at this as you may have already noticed

Comment: @a_guest I've provided an example of how the JSON code looks, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the builtin `json` module to process json. Here is a complete example.

```py
import json
# read the json file
json_txt = """[ { "name": "Box #14", "image": ".png", "attributes": [ { } ], "files": [ { } ] }, { "name": "Box #15", "image": ".png", "attributes": [ { } ], "files": [ { } ] } ]"""

data = json.loads(json_txt)
for val in data:
    number = int(val['name'].split('#')[1])
    val['image'] = f"{number-1}.png"

with open('json_output.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

This assumes that each part has a name and an image attribute.

For the actual data, you would be reading the file like so:

```py
with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Hi @Mohammad thanks for the help! Just tested your code and it runs fine but it doesn't apply any changes not sure where the issue is, I've edited my original post to show an example of 2 parts in a row. it's not editing the `"image": ".png"` bit at all

Comment: @Reiterating thanks, I've updated my answer according to your new example.

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly fine!